# Is it possible to create a mediawiki table where the columns are filled in by multiple templates?

Tags: templates, row, mediawiki, tabular

[Wikimedia explains how you can create a table](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Table/example_row_template) based on multiple templates, where each row is formed from a single template.

Is there anyway to do the same for columns? It sounds easy but I could not get it to work. Instead my page displayed multiple tables instead of multiple columns.

Here's some code:
**Row page**

```
{|class="wikitable sortable" style="font-size:85%"
|+ table name
! Title 1
! Title 2
! Title 3
|-
{{R1}}
{{R2}}
{{R3}}
|}
```

**Row template:**

```
| Row 1, Column 1
| Row 1, Column 2
| Row 1, Column 3
|-
```

**Column page**

```
{{C1}}{{C2}}{{C3}}
```

**Column template:**
Don't know how this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is impossible. I thought about it for a bit, and I have no idea how to do it.

Maybe some sort of nested Templates that rearrange the order of the columns and rows. Seems very difficult, and I'm not sure it's theoretically possible.

Comment: thx, I'm coming to this conclusion as well. Appreciate you giving it some thought.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know of, other than creating a virtual table with floating `<div>`s, is using [Labeled Section Transclusion](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLabeled_Section_Transclusion%20Extension%3aLabeled%20Section%20Transclusion) (or its equivalent `{{#dpl}}` function if you have [Extension:DynamicPageList](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aDynamicPageList_%28third-party%29)). You separately label each cell of your "column template" using `<section/>` tags or headings, and then create a framework table that fills in each row by transcluding from the column templates. The structure would look something like this:

```
{|class="wikitable sortable" style="font-size:85%"
|+ table name
! Title 1
! Title 2
! Title 3

|- valign="top
| {{#lst:col1|row1}}
| {{#lst:col2|row1}}
| {{#lst:col3|row1}}

|- valign="top
| {{#lst:col1|row2}}
| {{#lst:col2|row2}}
| {{#lst:col3|row2}}

|- valign="top
| {{#lst:col1|row3}}
| {{#lst:col2|row3}}
| {{#lst:col3|row3}}
...
|}
```

This solution lacks the simplicity of tossing out columns the way you can toss out rows, but sadly HTML just isn't designed to create true column-based tables. However, with this layout at least all the information from each column is stored on the same page where you can edit it more easily (`{{col1}}`, `{{col2}}`, etc.), and if you're recording textual information then you can also read each column as a distinct page which might be handy.

If you plan on doing this a lot, you can further simplify this by creating a template that fills in each row so you only need to specify the row number, something like this: (assuming your columns are always placed as subpages of the article where they will appear)

```
template:col-based table row
{{!}}- valign="top"
{{!}} {{#lst: {{PAGENAME}}/col1 | row{{{1|}}} }}
{{!}} {{#lst: {{PAGENAME}}/col2 | row{{{1|}}} }}
{{!}} {{#lst: {{PAGENAME}}/col3 | row{{{1|}}} }}
```

Then under the header you'd just need to list:

```
{{col-based table row|1}}
{{col-based table row|2}}
{{col-based table row|3}}
...
```

Now, if you want to automatically-generate these rows until you exhaust the template (or in other words, have the table determine how many rows to create without you manually setting them up), that I don't think I can help you with. Perhaps you can do something clever with the DPL extension's table generation function, or install an extension that will allow you to create loops, but I think you'll probably be stuck creating each row manually as described above.

As a final note, because this is content and not formatting I'd advise that you put the column pages in the mainspace rather than the template namespace. In fact, this is the sort of thing that subpages are great for.

Answer (score -1):

you could get the columns filled by templates using DIVs, but you wil have to recreate and re-size each cell within each div manually